# Quadratic Variation of Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, quadratic-variation

Quadratic Variation of a Brownian motion $B$ over the interval $[0,t]$ is defined as the limit in probability of any sequence of partitions $\Pi_n([0,t])=\{0=t^n_0<\cdots<t^n_{k(n)}=t\}$ of the interval $[0,t]$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\max_{i=1,\cdots,k(n)}|t^n_i-t^n_{i-1}|=0$, of the functional 
$$V([0,t],\Pi_n)(B_.)=\sum_{i=1}^{k(n)}(B_{t_{i-1}}-B_{t_i})^2.$$

And for any such sequence of partition we have then $[B]_t=P-\lim_{n\to \infty} V([0,t],\Pi_n)(B_.)=t$.

Nevertheless when you take the sup over all finite partitions of $[0,t]$ then it is a known fact that almost surely $\sup_{\Pi\in \mathrm{partition}([0,t])} V([0,t],\Pi)(B_.)=+\infty$.

I have never been able to derive this fact properly and in every details.

I'd be really gratefull if anyone could take the time to provide a detailed proof of this fact.

Comment: In addition to the answer below, these MIT lecture notes [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-070j-advanced-stochastic-processes-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT15_070JF13_Lec8.pdf) are also pretty decent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find a short proof of this fact (actually in the more general case of Fractional Brownian Motion) in the paper :

M. Prattelli :  *A remark on the 1/H-variation of the Fractional Brownian Motion*.  Probability Seminar Vol. XLIII ([pdf](http://www.dm.unipi.it/~pratelli/research/FBM.pdf))

Comment: @ pgassiat : Thank's this looks promising let me take a look at it.

Comment: Excellent proof !!! And note that for BM lemma 1 simplifies further as it is only Strong Law of Large Numbers (Brownian increments are i.i.d. in this context). Really thank you so much, I have been looking for such a detailed proof for years !!!

Comment: @The Bridge : You're welcome.

Comment: IMO, this should be added to every stochastic calculus book when talking about quadratic variation of Brownian Motion.

Comment: @TheBridge : Yes, I agree. Also if you are interested in a more precise result for BM, i.e. the "largest" $\varphi$ s.t. BM has finite $\varphi$-variation a.s., you can find in the paper "Exact asymptotic estimates of Brownian path variation",SJ Taylor, Duke Math. J. Volume 39, Number 2 (1972), 219-241.

Comment: @thebridge thanks for the link. I can't agree with you strongly enough that it should be in every stochastic calculus book. It was so confusing at first. Thank you so much.

Comment: The link seems to have changed - I believe https://people.dm.unipi.it/pratelli/research/FBM.pdf is the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

The book *Brownian Motion - An Introduction to Stochastic Processes* by René Schilling & Lothar Partzsch contains a (detailed) proof of this fact.