# What does it mean by multiplying two differentials in stochastic calculus?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I'm learning stochastic calculus right now at school and I'm coming across multiplication rules such as $$dW_t \cdot dW_t = dt$$ and I don't really quite understand what they meant. I tried looking up but I couldn't find any resources that explains this properly either. Originally, I thought it's supposed to mean that we can "multiply" two stochastic integrals in the sense that
$$ \int_0^t f(s, \omega)  dW_s  \cdot \int_0^t g(s, \omega) \, dW_s = \int_0^t f(s, \omega) \cdot g(s, \omega)  ds$$
where $f$ and $g$ are two functions on $[0,\infty) \times \Omega$ but this is not correct since if $f, g \equiv 1$ then the left hand side is random while the right hand side is deterministic. Can anyone explain this to me properly?

Comment: Your first formula is a sloppy notation for the quadratic variation $$d\langle W,W\rangle_t = dt\,.$$  If you put $\langle\;.\;\rangle$ around the LHS of the second equation it becomes acceptable. (To make it perfect the $t$ should be a subscript of $\Big\rangle$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, they are simply referring to the [quadratic variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_variation)

$$[X]_{t}=\lim_{|P|\to 0}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(X_{t_{k}}-X_{t_{k-1}})^{2},$$

where $P$ ranges over partitions of the interval $[0,t]$. For Brownian motion this converges to $t$ eg. [Is the fact that $dW_t\sim (dt)^{1/2}$ come from the $1/2-$holder property of Brownian motion?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3192106/is-the-fact-that-dw-t-sim-dt1-2-come-from-the-1-2-holder-property-of-br?noredirect=1&lq=1)