# On the quadratic variation of the Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales, variance, quadratic-variation

Since it is a martingale, it is easy to prove that $\mathrm{Var}[B]=\mathbb{E}([B,B]_t)$, where $[B,B]_t$ denotes the quadratic variation. But what is $[B,B]_t$ equal to, or equivalently what does
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\|\Pi\|\to 0}\sum_{i=0}^n(B_i-B_{i-1})^2
\end{equation}
converge in probability to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quadratic Variation of Brownian Motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92938/quadratic-variation-of-brownian-motion)

Comment: What I’m trying to ask is what it means  to have a ‘finite’ variation. A p-variation of a process is another stochastic process $[X]^p_t$. In what sense is $[X]^p_t$ finite? The link you posted show that its expectation is finite, but it is not enough I guess. Does that mean $[X]^p_t<+\infty$ almost surely? But I’ve never seen it proven anywhere.

Comment: One important thing to note is that for the quadratic variation process, the partition is fixed before choosing your outcome $\omega \in \Omega$, where (as in the link) the 2-variation is a supremum over all partitions, which will be infinite (for most paths of Brownian motion) even on a finite interval. Which are you talking about?

Comment: I'm referring to the quadratic variation, in the sense of your first definition @George

Comment: Yes, a positive random variable with finite expectation is finite almost surely.

Comment: @user6247850 according to what theroem?

Comment: That's a standard result in nearly every measure theory class.  It follows readily from Markov's inequality.

Comment: @ric.san it follows immediately from the definition of the integral for extended real valued functions