# Why is the Quadratic Variation true in Brownian Motion?

Tags: probability

**I am trying to understand why the Quadratic Variation property of Brownian Motion is true.**

That is, if $W$ is a Wiener Process (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process), then a very small change in the time results in an equally small change in position squared.

Mathematically, we can express the Quadratic Variation property as:

$$(dw^2) = dt$$

Here is my attempt to prove this:

We start with the following:

- A standard Brownian motion $W(t)$
- From the theoretical properties of a Wiener Process , we know that each increment $W(t_{j+1}) - W(t_j)$ is a random variable with a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance $t_{j+1} - t_j$.
- An $n$ number of partitions $\Pi = \{0 = t_0 < t_1 < \cdots < t_n = t\}$ of the interval $[0, t]$

Now, we need to prove:

$$[W, W](t) = \lim_{|\Pi| \rightarrow 0} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (W(t_{j+1}) - W(t_j))^2$$

Let's first define the change in position squared as:

$$Q_n = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (W(t_{j+1}) - W(t_j))^2$$

As a quick refresher, note the following identity for random variables in probability:

- $Var(X) = E(X^2) - [E(X)]^2$
- If $E(X)=0$, then the above identity directly relates variance to the expected value squared: $Var(X) = E(X^2)$

If we define a Wiener Process $X_t$ as:

$$X_t : W_{t+u} - W_t \sim N(0,u)$$

This basically implies that:

- $E(X_t) = 0$
- $Var(X_t) = u = E(X^2)$.

Going back, if we take the Expected Value of $Q_n$, we get (note: the Expected Value operator can be shifted inside the summation):

$$E[Q_n] = E\left[\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} [W(t_{j+1}) - W(t_j)]^2\right] = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} E[(W(t_{j+1}) - W(t_j))^2] = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (t_{j+1} - t_j) = t$$

This is the equivalent of saying:
$$E[Q_n] = t$$
$$E[(dw^2)] = dt$$

However, the original proof requires a conclusion on $Q_n$, not on $E(Q_n)$.

As a formality, we take the limit:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} E[Q_n] = Q_n = t$$

Thus, we have shown that for an infinite number of infinitesimally small partitions $n$ (i.e. limit as n approaches infinity), the quadratic difference is equal to $t$.

**Is my proof correct?**

Thanks!

- Note: Another way of seeing this is - for a single increment:

$$E[(W(t_{j+1}) - W(t_j))] = 0$$
$$[E[(W(t_{j+1}) - W(t_j))]]^2 = 0^2 = 0$$

$$Var[(W(t_{j+1}) - W(t_j))] = E[(W(t_{j+1}) - W(t_j))^2] -  [E[(W(t_{j+1}) - W(t_j))]]^2 = E[(W(t_{j+1}) - W(t_j))^2] - 0 = E[(W(t_{j+1}) - W(t_j))^2]$$

In summary:

$$E[(W(t_{j+1}) - W(t_j))^2] = Var[(W(t_{j+1}) - W(t_j))]$$

We always know that the variance of a a Wiener Process is directly proportional to its time difference: $Var[W_a - W_b] = b-a$

So in our case, the variance between $t_{j+1}$ and $t_{j}$ becomes:

$$Var[(W(t_{j+1}) - W(t_j))] = (j+1) - j = 1$$
$$E[(W(t_{j+1}) - W(t_j))^2] = Var[(W(t_{j+1}) - W(t_j))] = 1$$

Now if we sum this over $t$ increments, we get:

$$ Var[(W(t_{j+1}) - W(t_j))] = t \cdot 1 = t$$

This is another way to confirm the same result

Comment: What we need to prove is $$\color{red}{t}=\lim_{|\Pi| \rightarrow 0} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (W(t_{j+1}) - W(t_j))^2\,.$$ I do not see how taking the expectation of the RHS before doing the limit proves that.

Comment: One can show that, given a partition of the interval $[0, t]$, $$\lim_{|\Pi| \rightarrow 0} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (W(t_{j+1}) - W(t_j))^2 = t\quad\text{ in } L^2$$

Comment: kurt: do you have any ideas how I can prove this?

Comment: davide: can you show me how to prove this please?/

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1202838/949989) gives a few references.

Comment: @ Kurt G: I have been working on this question a few days ... here is my new attempt to prove this fact: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4879420/proving-properties-of-the-brownian-motion  can you please check it out if you have time? thank you so much